# How to remove li tags with in Particular DIV tag in notepad ++ using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have content like below

enter code here

```
<div class="content1">
<ul>
<li>line1</li>
<li>line2</li>
<li>line3</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="content2">
<ul>
<li>line4</li>
<li>line5</li>
<li>line6</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to strip all li tags within  and retain contents inside it. like below

```
enter code here
 <div class="content1">
 <ul>
 line1
 line2
 line3
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="content2">
 <ul>
 <li>line4</li>
 <li>line5</li>
 <li>line6</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

I have about 500 html files to edit.Is there any Regex code to achieve this in notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this

```
<li>(.*?)<\/li>
```

With the replacement string:

```
$1
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/etuAdK/1)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. what if i only want to remove li tags in  <div class="content1"> class.  li tags in <div class="content2"> must remain unchanged.

Comment: @Pmwarman regex is not the right tool if you need to manipulate html, you will need a html parser, traverse and manipulate the data.

Answer (score 0):

The regex to match those tags are

```
\<li\>
\<\/li\>
```

The backslashes are used to treat special characters as 'normal' characters.

If you use terminal you can use stream edit which is

```
sed 's/\<li\>//' input.txt > output.txt
```

But in notepad++ i believe you can ctrl find and replace

Comment: Thanks for the help. what if i only want to remove li tags in  <div class="content1"> class.  li tags in <div class="content2"> must remain unchanged.